# Is signed_request secure?

Tags: facebook, security

I'm creating a Facebook app. Facebook displays the app view in iframe and gives it signed_request in a POST parameter.

If someone get other's signed_request string, he can post it to the app.

```
curl -F "signed_request=CCuTU8c2…NjMwOTMxIn0" https://app.mydomain.xx/
```

Signed_request is registant to tampering. On the other hand, the app accepts the data which isn't tempered.

Should Facebook apps check something for it? For example, the value of issued_at. I wonder how to handle signed_request. Facebook's PHP SDK sets it to cookie. It's OK?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be faked, *if you check it properly*. It is a `JSON` data object that has been encrypted with your `application-secret`. An attacker would not be able to encrypt with this key, cos you never let anyone know it, right?  --if you have ever leaked your `application-secret`, your seriously boned in lots of other ways; a faked `signed_request` is the last of your worries.

You need to decrypt the data and parse the resultant `JSON` to ensure it matches the request you have received. If an attacker sends a `signed-request` that he has sniffed from  a previous use, then he can't just send it with an arbitrary request, as it will only match the request from which it was stolen. *But it is the responsibility of your code to perform this check*. It is possible that this may be a feature of your Facebook API client library, depending on the library and configuration used.

Please see the [signed request page at Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

And for further reading on Facebook security, please see the excellent [Developing Secure Facebook Apps](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Facebook) document at OWASP.

Comment: Thank you! and I'm sorry for my slow response.
My colleagues also said me that I'm too worry.